# Plot configuration - R

Tags: r, plot

I am having some issues to show the title of one of my plots after displaying other images (raster). Here is my case:

If all the plots are cleared in R and I plot it for the first time, the image looks correct, with its title

[image]

However, if I plot it after a raster image is displayed, the margins are changed and now, the appearence is different

[image]

`graphics.off()` kind of solve the issue but I do not want to delete any of the previous images since I need them.

Using `plot.new()` right before the `plot` command produces the same "wrong" layout without the title.

I have been checking `plot.new()`, `plot.default()` and `plot.window()` and would like to know which is the most straightforward method

Comment: From your question, it is not clear what type of object you are plotting, nor is it clear which method you are using the make plot. Please show a self-contained example (data and plot) perhaps taken from the help for the method you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing some test and it seems a solution would be to save the default parameters and then use them to reconfigure the plots:

```
dpar<-par() # Save default parameters before displaying anything

plot(raster) # Plot image that modifies default parameters

par(dpar) # Recall default parameters

plot(image) # plot the target image properly
```

For me it solved the issue but still wondering if this is the *appropriate* method